# C# Listview duplicating group name

Tags: c#, listview, grouping

```
if (comboBox1.Text == "1")
            {       
                int group1 = 0;

                group1 = listView1.Groups.Add(new ListViewGroup("Group 1"));

                listView1.ShowGroups = true;
                listView1.View = View.Details;


                string[] row = { textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text };

                ListViewItem lvi1 = new ListViewItem(row);


                lvi1.Group = listView1.Groups[group1];

                listView1.Items.Add(lvi1);

            }
```

If group 1 is selected and already been created, it should add the data to the group and not create a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do that:

1. Check if there already is a group one.
2. Delete the old group one and recreate it every time.

I'm definitely a fan of method 1, as it only requires a simple check. Method 2 will require more work to do, and if you want to work with the items in your `ListView`you'll get mad soon as they may not be there anymore (once they have been deleted and recreated).

---

Not sure if I got your question right btw, it may be helpful to elaborate a little on your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (comboBox1.Text == "1")
{       
    var groupLabel = "Group 1";
    var group = listView1.Groups[groupLabel];

    if (group == null)
    {   // group did not exist - let's create it and add it to the view
        group = new ListViewGroup(groupLabel);
        listView1.Groups.Add(group);
    }

    listView1.ShowGroups = true;
    listView1.View = View.Details;

    string[] row = { textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text };

    ListViewItem lvi1 = new ListViewItem(row) {Group = group};
    listView1.Items.Add(lvi1);
}
```

If you use the string indexer on the GroupCollection and a group with that string (ie name) does not exist you get a null. That's your clue to create it and insert it into the collection.

You could always encapsulate all of this in an extension class

```
public static class ListViewExt
{
  public ListViewGroup GetGroup(this ListView view, string groupLabel)
  {
    var group = view.Groups[groupLabel];

    if (group == null)
    {   // group did not exist - let's create it and add it to the view
        group = new ListViewGroup(groupLabel);
        view.Groups.Add(group);
    }   
    return group; 
  }
}
```

And then call it in your code:

```
if (comboBox1.Text == "1")
{       
    listView1.ShowGroups = true;
    listView1.View = View.Details;

    string[] row = { textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text };

    ListViewItem lvi1 = new ListViewItem(row) {Group = listView1.GetGroup("Group 1")};
    listView1.Items.Add(lvi1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution with accessing `listview.group[name]` always returned null.

So, I used some linq to achieve the same thing:

```
ListViewGroup lvg = this.listView_History.Groups.Cast<ListViewGroup>()
    .Where(x => x.Header == "MyString").FirstOrDefault();

if (lvg == null)
{
    lvg = new ListViewGroup("MyString");
    listView_History.Groups.Add(lvg)
}

ListViewItem LVI = new ListViewItem();
LVI.Group = lvg;
```